# $_GET[] only needs to run at certain times

Tags: php

**Scenario**:
I am currently writing an authentication function for a login page that sends an email to the user, you then click the email and it passes a link that sends them to login along with a UUID attached which verifies their account to be usable.

**Problem**:
My problem is that this page can also be reached by just opening the website, and their is no $auth variable passed. I need to be able to only get auth if it was passed the variable in the url. I need a way for my if statement to check if an auth variable was passed in the url.

**Code**:

```
if($_GET[ "auth" ]){
    $Auth = $_GET[ "auth" ];    
}
else{
    $Auth=NULL;
}

$db = new Database();
if($Auth != null){
    $check = $db->Authenticate($Auth);
    if($check != null){
        $error = $check;
    }
}
```

...

Comment: you're looking for [isset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if(isset($_GET[ "auth" ]))`

Try this :)